# How to display RGB24 video frame using opengl

Tags: opengl, rendering, rgb, rgba

My task is to render a set of 50 RGB frames using `openGL's` **glut** library.

**I tried:** In 3D cube rotation, i have a set of vertices using which i render it to the window. However, in case of rendering the RGB frames what should be done? Below is the code using which i render my 3d cube:

```
#include <glut.h>

GLfloat vertices[24]={-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0};
GLfloat colors[24]={-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0};
GLubyte cubeIndices[24]={0,3,2,1,2,3,7,6,0,4,7,3,1,2,6,5,4,5,6,7,0,1,5,4};
static GLfloat theta[3]={0,0,0};
static GLint axis=2;

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glLoadIdentity();
    glRotatef(theta[0],1.0,0.0,0.0);
    glRotatef(theta[1],0.0,1.0,0.0);
    glRotatef(theta[2],0.0,0.0,1.0);

    glDrawElements(GL_QUADS,24,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,cubeIndices);

    glutSwapBuffers();
    glFlush();
}

void spinCude()
{
    theta[axis]+=2.0;
    if(theta[axis]>360.0)
        theta[axis]-=360.0;
    display();
}
void init()
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glOrtho(-2.0,2.0,-2.0,2.0,-10.0,10.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void mouse(int btn,int state, int x,int y)
{
    if(btn==GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON&& state==GLUT_DOWN) axis=0;
    if(btn==GLUT_MIDDLE_BUTTON&& state==GLUT_DOWN) axis=1;
    if(btn==GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON&& state==GLUT_DOWN) axis=2;
}

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGB|GLUT_DEPTH);

    glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
    glutCreateWindow("Simple YUV Player");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    glutIdleFunc(spinCude);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,0,vertices);

    //glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,0,colors);

    glutMainLoop();

}
```

Can anyone suggest me some example or tutorial such that i can modify above code to display RGB frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have your RGB-Frame as raw-data in memory things are pretty straight-forward. Create a texture using `glGenTextures`, bind it using `glBindTexture` and upload the data via `glTexImage2D` or `glTexSubImage2D`. Then render a fullscreen quad or whatever you like with that texture. The benefit of that is that you could render multiple 'virtual' TVs in your scene just by rendering multiple quads with that same texture, imagine a TV-Store where the same video runs on dozen of TVs.
`glDrawPixels` might also work but it is much less versatile.

I don't know if uploading via texture is the way to go (hardware accelerated movie playback programs like VLC are most likely doing something far more advanced), but it should be a good start.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its really a good info. But i need a simple example or a code snippet involving the above instructions. Please suggest some link or some code and i will accept your answer. Please help.

Comment: Any basic texturing tutorial will work. There are tons of them on the net, for example http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/texture_mapping/12038/

Answer (score 0):

As Marius already suggested, implement texture mapping first. It's rather straigth forward any texture mapping tutorial will do.

Rendering frames are not the best with OpenGL you should try to avoid them as much as you can since it may involve a client -> host memory copy which is really costy ( takes too much time ) or simply it just takes up too much memory. Anyways if you really have to do it just generate as much textures as you need with glGenTextures load them up with the textures by glTexImage2D and then flip over the frames with a simple loop in each frame.

P.S. Judging by your application's name "YUV Player" you may also need to convert the input data since OpenGL mostly uses RGB not YUV.

Comment: Client -> host memory transfers aren't necessarily too costly. PCIe is the standards for many years now, and you could easily transfer some dozen megapixels per frame and still target 60fps. Note that if the input data is in YUV with chroma subsampling (which is not unlikely for digital video), the bandwith can be reduced even further by using the YUV data and doing the conversion to RGB on the GPU. Generating 50 textures in advance as you suggest (or using a 3D texture or texture array) might consume a lot of memory (depending on the image resolution).

Comment: Taking into account that this app is probably a test application you are right, altho if this supposed to be a live application you may want to avoid transferring frames real time even tho PCIe is fast it's got it limits as well. And yes 3D textures I forgot about those!

Comment: @derhass, what is faster solution ? lets say i decoded h264 stream using hardware decodint api - i have vector of uint_8 - what should i do next to display the frame without copying it to the host memory ? I am fairly new to the subject. Thank you!

Comment: @OleksandrPapchenko I don't know why you ask this, in some comment, addressed to me. Even when posted as a real question, I'd close-vote it as "too broad" (at least on the unspecific level this was asked). If you want to use GL for displaying videos, you'll have to learn GL first, and an article on stackoverflow can't teach that, nor is it intented to.